# Input type text to maximum of 2 digits

Tags: html, validation, input, html-input

I know that this is possible from `type="number"`but I cannot use this one because I also have `pattern` with some regex which is not compatible with it.

Is there a way to limit the input for `type="text"`? (In my particular case, to limit to maximum 2 digits after decimal point).

Comment: Specify it in your `pattern`.

Comment: You need to use letdown event and if user is trying to enter 3rd digit return false so user is not allowed to enter

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen the pattern already does something like that. it only matches the numbers with maximum 2 digits. the user can add more digits but it will not be validated. what I want is to not let introduce more than 2 digits in the input form. this is the regex I'm using " `^(?!0+(?:\\.0*)?(?:[eE]\\d+)?$)^\\d+(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?(?:[eE][0-9]{1,5})?$`

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene do you know where I can find an example of that? I searched but didn't find any

Answer (score 0):

if you want to limit the number of caracter on 2 caracters after the '.', you can check if the total number is realy a number

and stop the scripting after 2 caracters after the '.'

(i prevent the delete key with e.wich == 8)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById("numb").value;
    var carac = (e.which == 8) ? '' : String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var nbr = x + carac;
        if ( isNaN(nbr) ) {
          e.preventDefault();
          document.getElementById("numb").value = '';
          alert ( 'Please write a Number!' );
        }

    if(! Number.isInteger(nbr*100)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //document.getElementById("numb").value = '';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</p>

<input id="numb" type="text" onkeypress="myFunction(event)">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code let me write only 2 digits in general. What I want is to be able to write maxim of 2 digits after decimal point. e.g.: if I write 42342.14 I should not be able to write another digit